# string.format throws exception in http post request and response

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I would like to have a method for placing format specifiers (like %s) instead of placing hard code values, you can find my code bellow;

```
String userName = "Nicole";
    String password = "Nicole";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");

    String input=String.format("<soap:Envelope 

    xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:inn=\"http:Innovation/\">

    <soap:Header/><soap:Body><inn:getCategoriesbyVendorID><!--Optional:-->

    <userName>%s</userName><!--Optional:--><password>%s</password></inn:getCategoriesbyVendorID>

    </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",userName,password);

        //StringEntity input = new StringEntity("<soap:Envelope 

    xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:inn=\"http:Innovation/\">

    <soap:Header/><soap:Body><inn:getCategoriesbyVendorID><!--Optional:-->

    <userName>Nicole</userName><!--Optional:--><password>Nicole</password>

    </inn:getCategoriesbyVendorID></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");  

        post.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 

    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);
```

With the code above, the Entity throws an error. Could anybody help me solve this issue?

Comment: What is the exception (with the stacktrace)?

Comment: it is showing an error in eclipse i e.,change type of input to HTTP entity(post. set Entity(input);).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax of String formatting.

> It is showing an error in eclipse i e.,change type of input to HTTP
>   entity(post. set Entity(input);).

The error is because [`HttpPost.setEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) expects a parameter of type [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html?is-external=true) while you are specifying the type of String to it.

Try setting a [`org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) instead:

```
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(input); //Your formatted String 
post.setEntity(entity);
```